# Warning on node showing wrong node version. Could it cause sqlite3 Error?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, package.json

When running npm install I get the warning message:

```
npm WARN engine module@0.0.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.2.9 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
```

But in the package.json is specified node 5.3.0 (pls. see below)
Why does the message tell me the version 0.12 when the current version is 5.3?
Could it be the case for the error with sqlite3? I get the message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '...\node-v47-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
```

But in fact npm intall creates me node-**v14**-win32-x64 not node-**v47**-win32-x64 directory.

```
{
  "name": "aesku-hera",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor ./bin/www"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.3.0",
    "npm": "2.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.12.4",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "execsql": "0.0.3",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "gm": "^1.18.1",
    "jade": "^1.9.2",
    "jsonfile": "^2.2.3",
    "module": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "multer": "0.1.6",
    "node-hl7": "^0.1.3",
    "node-json-db": "^0.6.3",
    "node-mv": "^0.1.3",
    "periodic-task": "^0.1.0",
    "pg": "^4.4.0",
    "request": "^2.58.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.1",
    "string": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `engines` section in your package.json is just an indicator of which engine (like node) and the version your code would work on - see the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for more details.

It is most likely that your locally installed Node is version 0.12. You should upgrade it to 5.3.0 or higher and then try reinstalling your packages.

You can quickly verify your Node version by using the command -

`node -v`

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. node -v shows v5.3.0
The engines section was mendioned in a heroku tutorial. It helped me to fix deployment after I set correct versions. 
I don't understand the confusion with the versions: 0.12 as displayed for node in npm install, v14 of sqlite3 installed and v47 which is required by module.js and finally v5.3 actually installed. Should I unnstall all node-related stuff and install clean again?